# Is there any Java Testing Tool for manual tests?

Tags: testing

Basically, I want a free testing program that will allow me to create MANUAL tests with a series of steps where I can mark steps as passed or failed. I would like it to behave much like SpiraTest but it must be Non-web based.

In other words, I might write a test like:

```
Step    Description    Expected                Actual    Pass/Fail
1.      Run Program    Program should start              Pass
2.      Click Open     Open dialog displays              Pass
3.      Select file    Program opens file                Pass
```

Anyone know if such a thing exists?

And no, I do not want any automated testing stuff, this must be manual user testing. Thanks!

Comment: by non-web you really mean that the GUI should not be in a browser or just that you don't want a SAS product? For example Testlink (http://testlink.org/) is browser based but not SAS.

Comment: non web-based meaning that I don't want to have to setup an Apache server and install PHP and what not to use the program :)

I'm easily able to, but it needs to be able to be setup so that a person with little knowledge of computers can operate as a tester in the program (mindless manual testing is the end goal).

Answer (score 1):

[image]I use Excel / Spreadsheet for recording detailed test steps. I think that should pretty well solve your problem.